# Parsley data-parsley-error-message just presents global message within ul.parsley-errors-list

Tags: parsley.js

The global unique error message assigned via data-parsley-error-message is not returned when accessing the validation error messages through the `parsley().getErrorsMessages()` method.

According to the [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org), when clicking "Validate" [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xqonwq55/), I would expect the errors in the error list below the input and the errors listed in the textarea to be the same, but they are not.

I believe this to be a bug.  Can this please be confirmed?  Or, if my interpretation is not correct, can I get an explanation, and working example, of how data-parsley-error-message is intended to work?

(As one can see by the jsfiddle link above, I understand how to use `data-parlsey-required-message', that's not the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's definitely something wrong going on. Could you please open an issue?

I'll have to re-read the code, but in your example, it would make sense for the `data-parlsey-required-message` to have precedence here. If so, `getErrorsMessages()` is actually right but the wrong error is showing.